# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ind' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql, server

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ind' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp server\htdocs\Sahith\sy.php on line 13.

This error is shown when I run

```
    <?php   
    $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
    $dbuser = 'root';   
    $dbpass = '';   
    $se = ['index'];  

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  

    if(! $conn ) {    
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
     }    

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `Index No.` = '$se'';
    mysql_select_db('school'); 
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );   
   if(! $retval ) {     
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());  
     }    

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {  
   echo "Index  :{$row['Index No.']}  <br> ".   
    "NAME : {$row['Name']} <br> ".            "--------------------------------<br>";    }    
   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";   
   mysql_close($conn); ?>
```

this code

How to solve this???

Comment: stop using mysql use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: There's no `$ind` variable in the shown excerpt. // Also `$se = ['index'];` may not be a syntax error per se, it's certainly a semantic one.

Comment: This error also follows

Comment: I  have changed some thing but now a new error is shows "Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp server\htdocs\Sahith\searchprocess.php on line 15"

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `Index No.` = '$se'';
```

change to

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `Index No.` = "'.$se.'"';
```

Please have a look to : [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

And,

**WARNING:** Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and may compromise the security of your database and server. You should use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) APIs to secure your SQL queries, and using [`prepare`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) function.

Comment: Now I have blank page

Comment: @SahithyanKandathasan A blank page means generally that you have an error 500 (Internal Server Error). Check your Apache logs to solve this problem.